# How to start with IDP init SSO flow in SimpleSAMLPhp + (Laravel App + SP)

Tags: php, laravel, single-sign-on, saml-2.0, simplesamlphp

I've setup SimpleSAMLPhp as IDP and SP ([Laravel- SMAL2](https://github.com/aacotroneo/laravel-saml2)) in my Laravel App

Now how do i start with the SSO process means what will be the login url?
Will it be the same as given here https://simplesamlphp.org/docs/stable/simplesamlphp-idp#section_11

**Note:** I want to use same login url for multiple laravel websites

Comment: please refer to this amazing tutorial really helped me get through tough time https://www.lewisroberts.com/2015/09/05/single-sign-on-to-azure-ad-using-simplesamlphp/

Comment: I recently implement Microsoft Azure SAML login authentication in my project without using any library